# How to create a new html element?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to create a new HTML element, called test: `<test>some text</test>`

I tried to prototyping it like this: `HTMLUnknownElement.prototype.style.backgroundColor = "red";` but it doesn't work.

Could you please help me, how to manage it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should use CSS for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really a reason to do that.

When you want to create an element with red background, you should use an existing element and assign a CSS class to it which has red background (like `<span class="test">`) .

Answer (score 9):

How about [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement)?

```
var el = document.createElement("test");
el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

### edit

If we start with:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result will be:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <test style="background-color:red"></test>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. He wants to create a non-standard HTML tag `<test>`

Comment: @Philipp So what? It is still possible to do.

Comment: **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zVxVy/.

Comment: And that works? Strange, I would have never expected that.

Comment: @Philipp - and the code in this answer would create a non-standard HTML element with the tagname 'test' and apply a red background, just as the question asks, however invalid it may be.

Comment: `HTMLUnknownElement.prototype.innerHTML="this is a test"` also doesn't work. There may be something wrong with my prototyping

Comment: @HardRain You don't need to use prototype here. Check the DEMO from the third comment.